# convert csv file to list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I have a csv file

```
col1, col2, col3
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
```

I want to create a list of dictionary from this csv.

output as :

```
a= [{'col1':1, 'col2':2, 'col3':3}, {'col1':4, 'col2':5, 'col3':6}]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Use [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader):

```
import csv

with open('test.csv') as f:
    a = [{k: int(v) for k, v in row.items()}
        for row in csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True)]
```

Will result in :

```
[{'col2': 2, 'col3': 3, 'col1': 1}, {'col2': 5, 'col3': 6, 'col1': 4}]
```

Comment: For the lazy, from the linked page - `skipinitialspace`: When `True`, whitespace immediately following the delimiter is ignored.

Comment: @falsetru, Here why the output is not coming in this order? 
[{'col1':1, 'col2':2, 'col3':3}, {'col1':4, 'col2':5, 'col3':6}]

Comment: @V-T, Dictionary in python 3.6- is not an ordered collection.

Comment: @V-T, If you use Python 3.6+, OrderedDict which guarantee order: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

Comment: For unicode support on python2.7 you could use `import unicodecsv as csv`.

Comment: @falsetru: I see in your [linked docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) that as of Python 3.8 the return type is once again `dict`. Is there a way to explicitly enforce an order?

Comment: @hpy, Since Python 3.7+, insertion order of dict is guaranteed. https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html => Don't worry, just use DictReader :)

Comment: Whew, that's great to know. Thank you @falsetru! I wonder why that isn't mentioned in the documentation somewhere (or I probably missed it...)...

Comment: @hpy, It's mentioned in ["What's New In Python 3.7 - Summary - Release Hightlights"](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#summary-release-highlights) > Python data model improvements: > the insertion-order preservation nature of dict objects has been declared to be an official part of the Python language spec.

Comment: @hpy, also in [Built-in Types - `dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) > "Dictionaries preserve insertion order. Note that updating a key does not affect the order. Keys added after deletion are inserted at the end.", "Changed in version 3.7: Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order. This behavior was an implementation detail of CPython from 3.6."

Answer (score 40):

Another simpler answer:

```
import csv
with open("configure_column_mapping_logic.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    a = list(reader)
    print a
```

Comment: This turns it into a list of tuples, not dicts?

Comment: `print(a)` should be outside of the `with` block because at that time the file is no needed anymore. Additionally: why not `a = list(csv.DictReader(f))`?

Answer (score 10):

Using the `csv` module and a list comprehension:

```
import csv
with open('foo.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
    header = next(reader)
    a = [dict(zip(header, map(int, row))) for row in reader]
print a
```

**Output:**

```
[{'col3': 3, 'col2': 2, 'col1': 1}, {'col3': 6, 'col2': 5, 'col1': 4}]
```

Answer (score 6):

Answering here after long time as I don't see any updated/relevant answers.

```
df = pd.read_csv('Your csv file path')  
data = df.to_dict('records')
print( data )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# similar solution via namedtuple:    

import csv
from collections import namedtuple

with open('foo.csv') as f:
  fh = csv.reader(open(f, "rU"), delimiter=',', dialect=csv.excel_tab)
  headers = fh.next()
  Row = namedtuple('Row', headers)
  list_of_dicts = [Row._make(i)._asdict() for i in fh]
```

Comment: Only answer getting with same order of CSV

Answer (score 1):

Well, while other people were out doing it the smart way, I implemented it naively. I suppose my approach has the benefit of not needing any external modules, although it will probably fail with weird configurations of values. Here it is just for reference:

```
a = []
with open("csv.txt") as myfile:
    firstline = True
    for line in myfile:
        if firstline:
            mykeys = "".join(line.split()).split(',')
            firstline = False
        else:
            values = "".join(line.split()).split(',')
            a.append({mykeys[n]:values[n] for n in range(0,len(mykeys))})
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple method to parse CSV into list of dictionaries

```
with open('/home/mitul/Desktop/OPENEBS/test.csv', 'rb') as infile:
  header = infile.readline().split(",")
  for line in infile:
    fields = line.split(",")
    entry = {}
    for i,value in enumerate(fields):
      entry[header[i].strip()] = value.strip()
      data.append(entry)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for your question :

```
output = []

with open("test.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    data = csv_file.read().split("\n")

text = [data[i].split(",") for i in range(len(data))]

for i in range(1, len(text)) :
    output.append({text[0][num]:text[i][num] for num in range(len(text[i]))})
```

the output being the list of dico