# How to create a list of dictionaries from a csv file without list comprehension

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, for-loop, list-comprehension

The output must be like this:

```
[{'id': '1', 'first_name': 'Heidie','gender': 'Female'}, {'id': '2', 'first_name': 'Adaline', 'gender': 'Female'}, {...}
```

There is a code snippet that works, running this requirement.

```
with open('./test.csv', 'r') as file_read:
   reader = csv.DictReader(file_read, skipinitialspace=True)
   listDict = [{k: v for k, v in row.items()} for row in reader]
   print(listDict)
```

However, i can't understand some points about this code above:

1. List comprehension: `listDict = [{k: v for k, v in row.items()} for row in reader]`

   - How the python interpret this?
   - How does the compiler assemble a list always with the header (`id`,`first_name`, `gender`) and their values?
   - How would be the implementation of this code with nested `for`

I read theese answers, but i still do not understand:

- [python list comprehension double for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657720/python-list-comprehension-double-for)
- [convert csv file to list of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572175/convert-csv-file-to-list-of-dictionaries/21572244)

My csv file:

```
id,first_name,last_name,email,gender
1,Heidie,Philimore,hphilimore0@msu.edu,Female
2,Adaline,Wapplington,awapplington1@icq.com,Female
3,Erin,Copland,ecopland2@google.co.uk,Female
4,Way,Buckthought,wbuckthought3@usa.gov,Male
5,Adan,McComiskey,amccomiskey4@theatlantic.com,Male
6,Kilian,Creane,kcreane5@hud.gov,Male
7,Mandy,McManamon,mmcmanamon6@omniture.com,Female
8,Cherish,Futcher,cfutcher7@accuweather.com,Female
9,Dave,Tosney,dtosney8@businesswire.com,Male
10,Torr,Kiebes,tkiebes9@dyndns.org,Male
```

Comment: Could you post a sample of your `test.csv`?

Comment: @user5173426 done!

Comment: The comprehensions are a waste in this case. The dict comprehension is unneeded as every row already is a dict. The list comprehension is thus as well, since no further operations on elements are needed. A simple ˋlistDict = list(reader)ˋ should suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your list comprehension :

```
listDict = [{k: v for k, v in row.items()} for row in reader]
```

equals:

```
item_list = []

#go through every row
for row in reader:
    item_dict = {}
    #in every row go through each item
    for k,v in row.items():
        #add each items k,v to dict.
        item_dict[k] = v
    #append every item_dict to item_list
    item_list.append(item_dict)

print(item_list)
```

EDIT (some more explanation):

```
#lets create a list
list_ = [x ** 2 for x in range(0,10)]
print(list_)
```

this returns:

```
[0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81]
```

You can write this as:

```
 list_ = []
 for x in range(0,10):
     list_.append(x ** 2)
```

So in that example yes you read it 'backwards'

Now assume the next:

```
#lets create a list
list_ = [x ** 2 for x in range(0,10) if x % 2 == 0]
print(list_)
```

this returns:

```
[0,4,16,36,64]
```

You can write this as:

```
 list_ = []
 for x in range(0,10):
     if x % 2 == 0:
         list_.append(x ** 2)
```

So thats not 100% backwards, but it should be logical whats happening. Hope this helps you!

Comment: should i always read the list comprehension codes back to front? Besides that, how the `k` identifies always the header?

Comment: edited the post. hope its clearer. In the beginning its a 'weird' syntax, but as you get used to it, it saves you a lot of typing and actually becomes better readable ;)

Comment: This example is great! Thx