# Reading from text file. Making it to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a sample.txt file:

```
1 7 14
3 3 10
1 1 3
```

What I wrote (it is wrong but at least something)(there were better ones, but I couldn't remake them):

```
content = []
with open ("sample.txt","r",encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for line in file:
        line = file.readline().strip().split(" ")
        mydict = {"A":int(file.readline().strip().split(" ")[0]),
                  "B":int(file.readline().strip().split(" ")[1]),
                  "C":int(file.readline().strip().split(" ")[2])}
        content.append(mydict)

print (content)
```

expected output:

```
[ {"A":1,"B":7,"C":14},{"A":3,"B":3,"C":10},{"A":1,"B":1,"C":3} ]
```

Neither of them worked sadly.
There were 3 problems typically:

- When I try to convert the values with int()
- First or last line is missing (problem with indexing)
- At the values I can't write just simply line[0], because that way it is not working (why?)

I am really newbie, maybe it will be good for someone else who is doing the same as me and noob like me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert csv file to list of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21572175/convert-csv-file-to-list-of-dictionaries)

Comment: I hope this is a homework assignment, to teach you how to handle files and dictionaries. Otherwise, I'd suggest not to create such a list of dictionaries at all.

Comment: What you are missing is that `for line in file:` *already* reads the file a line at a time. Every call to `readline()` reads *another* line and so your input gets used up much quicker than you expect. Calling `readline()` is a lower-level (and older) approach that is an *alternative* to `for line in file:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close. The line variable is what you need:

```py
content = []
with open ("sample.txt","r",encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip().split(" ")
        mydict = {"A":int(line[0]),
                  "B":int(line[1]),
                  "C":int(line[2])}
        content.append(mydict)

print (content)
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a builtin csv reader that takes care of this for you very easily

```
import csv

result = list(csv.DictReader(open("myfile.csv"),["A","B","C"],delimiter=" "))
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are doing wrong is at

```
line = file.readline().strip().split(" ")
```

Here you are inside of a `for` that loops through each line. Check the output of the following

```
with open("sample.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line)
```

This will print each of the lines of the file.
So on first iteration it will print `1 7 14` on the second `3 3 10` and on the third `1 1 3`.

Now you are looping through each of the lines **But** while you are doing that you are **reading** the next line. Just check this out.

```
with open("sample.txt") as file:
    count = 0
    for line in file:
        print(count, "This is current line", line)
        print(count, "This is the next line",file.readline())
        count += 1 # count = count + 1
```

This simply outputs

```
0 This is current line 1 7 14
0 This is the next line 3 3 10
1 This is current line 1 1 3
1 This is the next line
```

So what you are doing is you are going trhough 2 lines at a time and thus you are correctly getting an index error.

Instead what you will have to do is just remove all the `readline` and read one line at a time. This is almost the same as @quamrana snippet.

```
content = []
with open ("sample.txt","r",encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for line in file: # Only 1 line at a time
        line = line.strip().split(" ") # .strip() removes all white space in the begging and end and also newlines
        mydict = {"A":int(line[0]),
                  "B":int(line[1]),
                  "C":int(line[2])}
        content.append(mydict)
```

Comment: Thank you, now I understand this. But when you wrote line.split(" ").strip() it wasn't good. But when it is strip().split(" ") it works. Why? (One of methods makes it a list if I remember correctly)

Comment: You are correct `line.split(" ")` is a list and this is calling `.strip()` on a list. The `strip().split(" ")` is first a string then is split. This is my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

in case you already using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("sample.txt",sep=' ', header=None)
df.columns = ['A','B','C']
print(df.to_dict('records'))
```