# Convert CSV file into list of dictionaries with precise type and order

Tags: python, csv

Everything is in the title, I've found this code that almost does what I want :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21572244/5455842

```
import csv

with open('test.csv') as f:
    a = [{k: int(v) for k, v in row.items()}
        for row in csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True)]
```

My CSV is made of 5 columns and 6 lines (the first one being fieldnames).

My problems are the following :

- the third column of my csv are date that needs to be datetime.date object
- the fourth column of my csv are multiple integer that needs to be a dict of int
- Let's say my fives columns are "1","2","3","4","5" : I need the code to make a list of dict in a precise order that is : 3,1,2,5,4

  Here's some sample data :

> ```
> Firstname,Lastname,Birthdate,Answers(good/middle/bad),Comments
> Mark,Tolonen,12/10/1986,"3154,0",The first one
> John,Travolta,02/18/1954,"42,21",Would grease again
> Albert,Einstein,03/14/1879,"18,19,20",This guy is not stupid
> Isaac,Newton,12/25/1642,"2000,20,20", Should eat apple
> Alan,Turing,06/23/1912,"42,42,42",Hey what's up
> ```

And here's a sample of desired thing :

```
[{'Birthdate': datetime.date(1986, 12, 10),
  'Comments': 'The first one',
  'Firstname': 'Mark',
  'Lastname': 'Tolonen',
  'Answers(good/middle/bad)': [3154, 0]},
 {'Birthdate': datetime.date(1954, 02, 18),
  'Comments': 'Would grease again',
  'Firstname': 'John',
  'Lastname': 'Travolta',
  'Answers(good/middle/bad)': [42, 21]},
...
}]
```

Comment: Show some sample data.  What is the date format?  What does "multiple integer that needs to be a dict of int" look like.  "list of dict in a precise order" is unclear as well.  Dictionaries don't have an order before Python 3.7, and after that it is key insertion order, so might be possible depending on what *precisely* you are looking for.  Give sample *desired* output as well.

Comment: I may have described thing the bad way but here's a concrete example so you will understand what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: As mentioned above, dictionaries in python are not an ordered data structure, despite the enhancements in 3.7.  Why do you care about the order within the dictionary?  That answer may help get to a better result

Comment: The answer is simple, it's because I want to do so, isn't there a way to cast is to something more "ordered" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your sample data and desired output, if you use Python 3.7 or later, the dictionary order will be as desired:

```py
import csv
from datetime import datetime
from pprint import pprint

order = 'Birthdate','Comments','Firstname','Lastname','Answers(good/middle/bad)'

with open('input.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    data = []

    for row in reader:

        # Post-process the non-string columns.
        row['Birthdate'] = datetime.strptime(row['Birthdate'],'%m/%d/%Y').date()
        row['Answers(good/middle/bad)'] = [int(x) for x in row['Answers(good/middle/bad)'].split(',')]

        # Re-write the dict with the desired key order.
        # Python 3.7 (or CPython 3.6) or later required to keep insertion order.
        # 3.7 made insertion order preservation part of the language spec.
        # Specifically, the implementation of CPython 3.6 preserves insertion order
        # as an implementation detail.
        # For older versions use collections.OrderedDict instead.
        data.append({k:row[k] for k in order})
        
pprint(data)
```

Output:

```
[{'Birthdate': datetime.date(1986, 12, 10),
  'Comments': 'The first one',
  'Firstname': 'Mark',
  'Lastname': 'Tolonen',
  'Answers(good/middle/bad)': [3154, 0]},
 {'Birthdate': datetime.date(1954, 2, 18),
  'Comments': 'Would grease again',
  'Firstname': 'John',
  'Lastname': 'Travolta',
  'Answers(good/middle/bad)': [42, 21]},
 {'Birthdate': datetime.date(1879, 3, 14),
  'Comments': 'This guy is not stupid',
  'Firstname': 'Albert',
  'Lastname': 'Einstein',
  'Answers(good/middle/bad)': [18, 19, 20]},
 {'Birthdate': datetime.date(1642, 12, 25),
  'Comments': ' Should eat apple',
  'Firstname': 'Isaac',
  'Lastname': 'Newton',
  'Answers(good/middle/bad)': [2000, 20, 20]},
 {'Birthdate': datetime.date(1912, 6, 23),
  'Comments': "Hey what's up",
  'Firstname': 'Alan',
  'Lastname': 'Turing',
  'Answers(good/middle/bad)': [42, 42, 42]}]
```

Comment: Thank you SO much, you made my whole week! I was about to have the same output but with a shiton of unecessary lines of code, I'll learn so much from it for sure
Have your best week boss